# Unexpected bound

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile this new class :

```
public class WindowedGame
        extends GameContainer<GameType extends Game<Graphics2D>> {
    ...
}
```

This class extends the class :

```
public abstract class GameContainer<GameType extends Game<?>> {
    ....
}
```

Can you suggest me a correction or explain to me why I get the error :

> Unexpected bounds

Thanks!

Comment: You removed everything relevant from the code. Give us some more context.

Comment: @rekire He posted everything one needs to answer this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GameType` is the generic type parameter name, so it cannot be in the `extends` clause.

If `WindowedGame` should be generic, define it as

```
public class WindowedGame<GameType extends Game<Graphics2D>>
        extends GameContainer<GameType> {
    ...
}
```

If `WindowedGame` shouldn't be generic, perhaps you meant to define it as

```
public class WindowedGame
        extends GameContainer<Game<Graphics2D>> {
    ...
}
```

BTW, the naming convention for generic type parameter names is often a single upper case character (`T`, `E`, etc...). It would be less confusing if instead of `GameType` you write `T`.

```
public class WindowedGame<T extends Game<Graphics2D>>
        extends GameContainer<T> {
    ...
}

public abstract class GameContainer<T extends Game<?>> {
    ....
}
```

Comment: "GameType is the generic type parameter name, so it cannot be in the extends clause."

Could you clarify that?

Do you mean that the usage of GameType here is wrong:
GameContainer<GameType extends Game<Graphics2D>>